# Why is my Twitter links not displaying image?

Tags: twitter

SImple question: If I post a link to my website on twitter, the image does not appear even though I checked the link on twitter card validator and the image and the link work well there.
Here is the link: https://globalgoodness.ca/unehistoiredhommesdelephantsetdabeilles/

Thanks for the help (and plz consider that I am a twitter "illiterate :)

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code

Comment: I've just tried Tweeting that exact link and the image shows up just fine.